# How to create a public UX process?

Tags: social-media, design-process, facebook

I want to make an experiment. I have a new project that I don't mind opening to the public.

What I want to try is to use the public (e.g. Facebook) to go through a UX design process - from collecting stories down to testing the final product.

What do you think would be the right process and steps I should go through?

Answer (score 3):

Nice Idea, I like this. The key thing is that you can totally leverage the power  of crowdsourcing here not just from the point of view of getting design reviews but also in other areas.The steps I would suggest are:

1. Create a project site about your proposed project and propagate it around as much as possible.How you do this will depend upon you but methods like public shares,digg,voice of mouth and even press can help greatly. This will ensure more people visit your project page and get an idea about what its about and ensure you have the facebook page for the project linked there prominently so that people can go and "Like" it. This will help in building the user base
2. Use your project Facebook page to elicit opinions about stories of similar projects and what people love or hate about them. Another way to get more information and start a discussion would be to see if any article/blog about your proposed project has a Facebook commenting system so that you can have users directly comment from Facebook. Getting feedback and opinions this way will help you understand the project space and issues at hand and what people would love to have or like about an existing project
3. Come up with some preliminary designs and show it on Facebook and ask for inputs.If possible,also include the users by asking them to provide their own designs or hold a kind of design competition which would not only help you get some interesting designs but also an idea of the mental model of the user.Once you have got some good designs/feedback keep iterating through them and ask people for inputs. Do note that since you would be mostly showing static screens, you might not be able to show the interaction too well,so define clearly what your major interactions are so that people are able to notice them as they go from photo to photo
4. While doing all this ,do keep on keeping people involved by calling them out for excellent inputs and design ideas.People like to be encouraged and public support from a whole group of strangers who agree on their inputs can be gratifying. Remember your success depends on the sustained interest of your users,so try to keep your Facebook page fresh and interesting
5. I am not sure what your funding for this project is but use facebook as a recruiting tool for online usability testing and getting feedback. Sometimes users might for usability testing if they believe in a cause but sometimes you have to provide some kind of an incentive. Alternatively you can use the tools offered by facebook such the commenting system,surveys,polls to get feedback about design aspects
6. Once a final design is made after repeated iterations, allow users to download it/ play with it and encourage them to give their feedback and the challenges they found.

I know the [iron sky movie](https://www.facebook.com/ironsky) wasnt a design project but I really loved how they used social media to get  a huge fan base to get inputs and kept them informed about the whole process and created a pretty decent movie completely from crowd sourcing help

Comment: +1 For providing a more extensive answer than mine. Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Great idea! I'd love to follow this one on Facebook. You could use your own design process or a regular one such as this one:

[image: Design process from edc.org]
<sup>Image from [edc.org](http://cct2.edc.org/imagination_place/guide/design.htm)</sup>

One idea would be to present the design process as early on as possible. Interested users would then have the possibility to grasp the design process from a conceptual level. They would then know where in the process you are when you post to your facebook page.

Good Luck!